# Passing selected value to MVC view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout-2.0

Just basic Question:
I have list of strings in the model

```
public class TeacherModel
{
   public List<string> fullCourse { get; set; }
}
```

in the view I can bind the list values either :

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Name,new SelectList(Model.fullCourse));
```

Or using Knockout viewModel:

```
<select data-bind="options:info2, optionsCaption:'Choose', value:chosenInfo "></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function AppViewModel() {
       this.info2 = ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.fullCourse)));
```

```
 this.chosenInfo=ko.observable();

        };
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

</script>
```

Now: I'm trying to pass select value to another view:

- `@Html.ActionLink("View Details",    "about",    "Home",   ??????, null);`
  Or:
- `@ViewBag["mydata"]=????`

thanks alot

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink()` is razor code and is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. If you want to send the value of the user selected option, you need to use javascript to create the url based on the selected value (and then you can use `location.href = url;` to redirect)

Comment: Thanks, could you suggest link or similar approach topic?